# Amazon RDS: I follow all the instructions for creating a new RDS instance and setting my inbound rules correctly and yet cannot connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

What I'm looking for is a better step by step explanation, as I followed Amazon's and the instance is available, the security group has inbound and outbound all traffic allowed at my IP (I also tried "anywhere" and that didn't work either).  I also added my public whoami IP address to the CIDRs in the vpc I'm using with /24 after it as instructed by Amazon.

Is there another step that I'm unaware of?    Something else that could be causing me to be unable to connect?

Comment: Are you able to ping the dns name?

Comment: If you are trying to access the RDS server from outside the VPC then you need to enable the "publicly accessible" flag in the RDS instance configuration.